# Is there a blackboard version of Omega (the capital letter)

Tags: symbols, blackboard

Is there a way to write a blackboard version of the Greek capital letter Omega in LaTeX?

Comment: I must confess to never having encountered double-struck (aka blackboard or blackboard-bold) uppercase **Greek** letters. However, that may just be a reflection of my limited knowledge. Maybe, just maybe, there is indeed a math font out there which features a double-struck uppercase letter Omega.

Comment: There are the `bbold` fonts. Sans-serif, however.

Comment: @Mico Kind friend, I have removed my duplicate of a question.