# Blackboard type \Omega symbol

Tags: fonts, symbols

I would like to produce a capital Greek letter \Omega in blackboard type font.
This is related to the question: [Is there a blackboard version of Omega (the capital letter)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/412992/is-there-a-blackboard-version-of-omega-the-capital-letter).
However, this one has been marked as answered whereas I do not find it really true. In particular, the related answer proposes *e.g.* using \bbm which does not work for me.

An alternative would be to use \bbold. My problem is that I want to use \mathbb for my text and only \bbold to define my capital letter. So I try this at the beginning of my document:

```
\usepackage{bbold}
\newcommand{\OO}{\bb{\Omega}}
```

But I have two problems: first, \bb{\Omega} does not seem to be the solution to produce my capital letter; on the other hand, I do not know how to use again \mathbb after having defined my \OO symbol.

Any suggestion would be appreciated!

Comment: Please, can you add an image to understand your problem? For example for me it is important a figure or a MWE that I can compile to see the output.

Comment: @Sebastiano Well I did not find any solution to my problem, so I do not have any example/picture to show you. To rephrase my wish: I would like to use the Greek letter \Omega in blackboard font, that is, replace the "A" letter in \mathbb{A} by the letter "\Omega". Any font which looks like to it would be fine as well.

Comment: If you want only one symbol from "another" font, this question should help: [Importing a single symbol from a different font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386)

Comment: Thank you @barbarabeeton

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple solution is to declare another “math alphabet” with a different name:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathmybb}{U}{bbold}{m}{n}

\newcommand*{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand*{\BOmega}{\mathmybb{\Omega}}



\begin{document}

The usual~$\R$.
The boldfaced omega: $\BOmega$

\end{document}
```